# How does an installed app use storage?

Tags: android

I'm building an app that will contain a fair amount of resources (video) and need to better understand the impact a large APK will have on users. As an experiment I located a 32MB APK (which contains lots of video) and installed it on a Nexus One. Before installation the phone showed 36MB free internal storage. After installation is showed 33MB (not the ~4MB I was expecting).

How has a 32MB app been installed in such a way that only 3MB of internal storage has been used?

If anyone can clarify or point me to a resource that explains how internal memory is used by installed app, that'd be great.

Comment: Are you sure that your APK size is really 32MB? An APK is a simple zip file, so its size can be greatly reduced compared to the total size of your resources.

Comment: The APK is definitely 32MB. It's full of video files, which is why it is big, but that is not the question I asked.

Comment: I checked the app settings and the app has been moved to the SD card. I did not manually move it, so how has the app ended up on the sd card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App is probably installed on external storage e.g. "moved" to flash memory card. Still some small amount of internal memory is used.

It's always good to enable "move to SD card" feature though app home widget will be disabled if app is moved to SD card.

Comment: I haven't moved it to external storage. Are you saying an app can be set up to automatically install itself to external storage? If so, why is it using 3MB of internal storage, not none?

Comment: If you are using android:installLocation="preferExternal" or android:installLocation="auto" system could automatically install app to external storage. This can be checked in Settings/Applications/Menage Applications/your application. If you do not use it then I am not sure why you are experiencing this issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The app is set to prefer external storage.